# Report Percentage formatting

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am currently using SSRS 2012 and having a small issuing with formatting of percentages, my current calculation is Profit/Loss divided by total of Sell Customer and Sell Warranty this is just for readers background purposes, usually when I have the calculation in the cell that I want I just format with the letter P.  The problem I have is my Profit/Loss figure is -£6284.31 and would be divided by £237.00 which should give me a figure of -26.51% but using the same option I have done everywhere else I am left with -2,651.61% is there a different type of format mask I should be using rather than P as I want all percentages down to 2 places after the decimal point.

Hope that is enough information.

Thanks Phil

Comment: Are you multiplying by 100 before formatting? Ie is the data value -0.26516 or 26.516?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format you want to use is `P2`. When using a percentage format the value is automatically multiplied by 100 (-26.51 * 100 is the -2,651.61 that you are seeing). Essentially, all you need to do is divide the result of your profit/loss figure by 100.